# Send a string from javascript to php (in the same file)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So basically, I got a php file where I create a script in the header.

In this script, I take the value of two textbox with `document.getElementByID` and I concatenate them in a variable. But now, in the same script, I want to send that `var` to a php section to use it.

I tried the ajax way, but since the php and the javascript is in the same file, it make an error.

Here is what the script section looks like :

**IN FILE.PHP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rowNum = 0;
    function some_function()
    {    
        var command = "somebasiccommand";

        if(document.getElementById("text_1").value != "" && document.getElementById("text_2").value != "")
        {
            command += " " + document.getElementById("text_1").value + " " + document.getElementById("text_2").value;
        }               

        <?php

            $parameter = command; <----- obviously not working, but that's basically what im looking for

            $output = exec("someExecutable.exe $parameter");

                                (...)
        ?>
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT 1**

So here it is, I tried to use ajax this time, but this isn't working, seems like i miss something. Here is the server.php:

```
<?php

$parameter = $_POST['command']; 

$output = exec("someexecutable.exe $parameter");
$output_array = preg_split("/[\n]+/",  $output); 
print_r($parameter);
?>
```

And here is my ajax call in my client.php (in a js script):

```
var command = "find";

        if(document.getElementById("text_1").value != "" && document.getElementById("text_2").value != "")
        {
            command += " " + document.getElementById("text_1").value + " " + document.getElementById("text_2").value;
        }   

        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest;
        ajax.open("POST", "server.php", true);
        ajax.send(command);
        var output_array = ajax.responseText;
        alert(output_array);
```

For some reason, it doesn't go farther then the ajax.open step. On the debugger console of IE10, i got this error : SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'open' .

Comment: the php file needs to be on a separate page. And then you can get it either through GET or POST.

Comment: what is your browser? (IE or FF)
Your error mean that browser not support XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I use IE10 and it seems like it should support it... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run a serverside script in your ClientSide script, 
that's never going to work.

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

If you want to do something with the data from text_1 and text_2, you should create a php file that can handle a post/get request via AJAX or a simple submit, featuring the data from those elements, and make it return or do whatever it is you want it to end up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use javascript variable (client) from php (server). To do that, you must call ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    rowNum = 0;
    function some_function()
    {    
         var command = "somebasiccommand";
         if(document.getElementById("text_1").value != "" && document.getElementById("text_2").value != "")
         {
            command += " " + document.getElementById("text_1").value + " " + document.getElementById("text_2").value;
         }               
        //AJAX call to a php file on server
       //below is example
       var ajax = window.XMLHttpRequest;
       ajax.open("POST", "yourhost.com/execute.php", true);
       ajax.send(command);   
    }
</script>
```

And this is **execute.php** on server

```
<?php
        $parameter = $_POST['command']; 

        $output = exec("someExecutable.exe $parameter");

         (...)

?>
```

Comment: The problem is, after I get $output, I close the php section to use this value into a javascript instruction. Otherwise, I don't know how to access the php data in the original file. Normally I was just using <?php $myvalue ?> since it was in the same file. Do you know how?

Comment: do you try below js code when you got $output:
`ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
    {
    alert(ajax.responseText);
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Alright... I pretty much changed and tested many things and I found out that the problem was the async property of the .send command. I was checking the value of the respondText too fast. Putting the third property of .open to false made the communication sync, so I receive the infos properly. I got another problem right now, but its not the same thing, so I will do another post.